# MathML not representing on CKedtior 4 on Chrom broswer

Tags: java, google-chrome, ckeditor, mathml

Hi,

I am facing problem while loading MathML type of content on CKEditor V4 For Google Chrome browser.

- On Mozilla Math ML content working and expected result screen shot attached here(Mozilli_MathML_works.png)
- On Chome Math ML content not working screen short attached here(Chrom_MathML_NotWorking.png)

MathML content : {
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mfenced separators="|"><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>a</mi></mrow></mfenced></mrow><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow></msup><mo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">=</mo><mrow xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msubsup><mo stretchy="true">&sum;</mo><mrow><mi>k</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn></mrow><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow></msubsup><mrow><mfenced separators="|"><mrow><mfrac linethickness="0pt"><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>k</mi></mrow></mfrac></mrow></mfenced><msup><mrow><mi>x</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>k</mi></mrow></msup><msup><mrow><mi>a</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>n</mi><mo>-</mo><mi>k</mi></mrow></msup></mrow></mrow></math>
}

**Code :**

CKeditorV4 :
[
var editortextObj= CKEDITOR.replace("editorArea");

editortextObj.setData(MathMLcontent);
]

Thank you if any one can help us regard this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nitin. Could you maybe post your code in this question? That would be helpful in finding the answer.

Comment: Yes right, I added code too. Thank you lliass Nassibane